# Is it possible to change BackgroundColor of snackbar for ios?

Tags: ios, swift, snackbar, material-components

My app uses a snackbar of material-components-ios. I want to change `BackgroundColor` to blue, but I can't.

So is it possible to change the background color of snackbar?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You have to hack it. :)

In your pods there is a file called.

> MDCSnackbarMessageView.m

there is  function like this. I changed the value already to blue. And it will take hex value color code.

```
- (UIColor *)snackbarBackgroundColor {
   // return MDCRGBAColor(0x32, 0x32, 0x32, 1.0f); //previous grey color
    return MDCRGBAColor(0x10, 0x3F, 0xFF, 1.0f);// blue color
}
```

Now do, **clean and build** again. Here is the output.

[image]

Comment: @ozzotto take a look at my answer

Comment: Answer below from @Kumuluzz should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks you. How to change button tintcolor?

Answer (score 23):

You don't have to hack it :-)

Since you have added the `swift` tag to this question, then I'll give an answer with Swift code.

```
MDCSnackbarMessageView.appearance().snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor = .green
MDCSnackbarManager.show(MDCSnackbarMessage(text: "Hi there"))
```

Comment: @user3659077: Great, let me know if it works! If you find the solution better than the previous answer, then feel free to change the accepted answer to mine :-) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 5):

I'm using MaterialComponents version 68.1. If you too, try this:

```
let message = MDCSnackbarMessage()
message.text = "message"

MDCSnackbarManager.messageTextColor = .white
MDCSnackbarManager.snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor = .blue
MDCSnackbarManager.show(message)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that :

```
MDCSnackbarManager.default.snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

I also created a wrapper class to simplify usage :

```
import MaterialComponents.MaterialSnackbar

class Snackbar {
    
    static func show(message: String,
                     actionMessage: String? = nil ,
                     actionHandler: MDCSnackbarMessageActionHandler? = nil,
                     messageTextColor: UIColor? = nil,
                     snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor: UIColor? = nil,
                     buttonTitleColor: UIColor? = nil){
        
        MDCSnackbarManager.default.snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor = snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor
        MDCSnackbarManager.default.messageTextColor = messageTextColor
        MDCSnackbarManager.default.setButtonTitleColor(buttonTitleColor ?? UIColor.white, for: .normal)

        let snackbarMessage = MDCSnackbarMessage()
        snackbarMessage.text = message
        if(actionMessage != nil && actionHandler != nil){
            let snackbarMessageAction = MDCSnackbarMessageAction()
            snackbarMessageAction.handler = actionHandler
            snackbarMessageAction.title = actionMessage
            snackbarMessage.action = snackbarMessageAction
        }

        MDCSnackbarManager.default.show(snackbarMessage)
    }
    
 
}
```

Usage :

```
Snackbar.show(message: "Super message", snackbarMessageViewBackgroundColor: UIColor.blue)
```